# sessionStorage.token() defaulting to last values regardless of choice

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, backend

I am trying to assign a storageToken to another page depending on what the user selects in the previous page(menuBar) and I figured this was a decent way of going about it but regardless of what the user selects it always defaults to the last sessionStorage.token created which is pride, here is the code :

```
 <Link
                to={"/Collections/Equality"}
                onClick={sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Equality")}
              >
                Equality
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                to={"/Collections/Political"}
                onClick={sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Political")}
              >
                Political
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                to={"/Collections/Covid"}
                onClick={sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Covid")}
```

I then use it in my other page like this:

```
  let shirts = products.filter(product => product.category === sessionStorage.getItem("collectionName"));
```

anyone know why this is occurring or do you all have a better way to pass something to the other page depending on a click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change onClick handler as seen below

```
onClick={() => sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Equality")}
```

Full Code

```
<Link
            to={"/Collections/Equality"}
            onClick={() => sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Equality")}
          >
            Equality
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            to={"/Collections/Political"}
            onClick={() => sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Political")}
          >
            Political
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            to={"/Collections/Covid"}
            onClick={() => sessionStorage.setItem("collectionName", "Covid")}
```

Comment: So now this is only returning the first one, in my case its only returning Equality regardless of which one i chose?

Comment: as a better way you could actually parameterize the collection name in the router path than storing it in sessionStorage.

Comment: So the router path would be like /collection/{collectionName}? Then how would i go about using that to only filter the specific items under that value? Im new to backend work and javascript in general so sorry for dumb questions

Comment: let shirts = products.filter(product => product.category === params.collectionName);

Comment: Okay I added /collection/{collectionName} to my routes and i have the <Link> set to /Collections/Equality, but now im getting a blank page, im guessing its something to do with the new route?

Comment: if the route is ```/collection/{collectionName}``` then the Link to should be  ```/collection/Equality```. Check the route paths

Comment: Okay it was because i guess its suppose to be /collection/:collectionName for params? But now im getting params is not defined inside the other page that is pulling from it?

Comment: check this page https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params for how to use url params

Comment: Wow this works way better! Thank you for helping me learn a new technique!